# Python xpath returns an empty list

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, lxml

I need to extract some of the `href` attributes under the "ARTICLES" section on [this page](http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/11contents.html).
I am using the following code

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://www.dlib.org/dlib/november14/11contents.html')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

result = tree.xpath('/html/body/form/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table[5]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/p[6]/@href')
print result
```

I know for sure that the XPath is correct but when I run the script it prints 
`[]`

I've tried with some others elements on the page and it works as expected.

Any idea?

Comment: Does it work if you drop the `tbody` steps, i.e. use `/html/body/form/table[3]/tr/td/table[5]/tr/td/table/tr/td[2]/p[6]/@href`? There are no `tbody` elements in the source code of that HTML documents so perhaps your parser does not add them, as the browser's HTML parsers do.

Comment: This document is XHTML, effectively that's XML with a default namespace. Check out answers that show how to work with XHTML in Python.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thank you man, it worked!